# Java Web App Inserting into mysql, best way

Tags: java, mysql

So I'm building a register/login form on java web app and I want to make it nearly perfect. By that I mean secure, fast, clean code.

So right now my code is like that. I have a private structure of User, with setters and getters and a method of registration:

```
db dbconn = new db();
Connection myconnection = dbconn.Connection();
String sqlString = "INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ('"+Name+"','"+Password+"')";
try {
    Statement myStatement = null;
    myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlString);
    myStatement.close();
    myconnection.close();
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

But the thing is I heard ( not sure ) that just running SQL queries like that is bad example and I shouldn't do that? So I'm just wondering, what is the best way to register a user into my MySQL database? Using procedures? Or is using Statement like that is valid as well?

Comment: use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Do you know hibernate? I think you should use hibernate which is very popular in many real projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just use JDBC (and not an OR mapper) you should use prepared statements due to security reasons. The way you're doing it allows for SQL injection.

Problem: if you concatenate parameter values like you do one could alter the query.

Example: if `Name` had the value `x','y');DELETE FROM users;SELECT * FROM users WHERE name in ('whatever`

the query would become:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ('x','y');DELETE FROM users;SELECT * FROM users WHERE name in ('whatever', 'password')
```

Now execute that query and you might wonder where all the users are gone.

Using a `PreparedStatement` the statement would look like this:

```
PreparedStatement pst = myconnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?,?)");
pst.setString(1, Name); //btw, Java coding conventions state it should be "name" instead of "Name"
pst.setString(2, Password); //your password should be hashed and salted btw!
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Note how it's not necessary to use single quotes in the statement. `PreparedStatement` will handle that for you and also escape the values to prevent injection.

A second thought (from a design point of view): you might think about separating user registration etc. from the user objects holding the data (see Single responsibility principle). This is just meant to be a suggestion and there surely are others that don't agree (with valid arguments, often depending on the situation though).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wrote myself almost exactly looking statement like yours online mine had excecuteQuery instead of excecuteUpdate ( not sure what is the difference )

Comment: @Argus read the JavaDoc. `executeQuery` will return a `ResultSet`  while `executeUpdate` returns the number of updated rows. I'm not sure if `executeQuery` would work here but assuming it does you'd have to extract the returned number of affected rows yourself from the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

- Move

> db dbconn = new db(); Connection myconnection = dbconn.Connection();

To a utility class.

- As proposed in the comments, use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid SQL injections and String concatenations (use ? and don't try to concatenate)
- I would put all SQL statements in a util class as public static final String
- See some real world examples on how to do it, for example use a finally block to close the statement and the connection (it will look ugly with the try/catch also inside the finally block)
- Here's a [link](https://dzone.com/refcardz/jdbc-best-practices) to a JDBC best practices refcard (although a bit advanced)
- A couple reference small tutorials:

  [Vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

  [Oracle's official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)